# Windows Server 2012 DNS Forward Lookup Zone missing sub zones

Tags: windows-server-2012, dns-zone

My client has been having DNS issues for the past couple months. I noticed that their Forward Loopup Zone is all screwed up and missing a bunch of subfolders (ie. gc, dc, pdc, domains, _sites, _tcp, _udp, etc.) They are a single server network, running their entire AD, DNS, DHCP from this one server.

What steps should I take to reinstate these missing items?

Eric

Comment: Does the _msdcs zone exist? All of those items that you listed are typically in that zone and not the domain's forward lookup zone.

Comment: Is "Filter" selected under the View menu?

Answer (score 0):

There would be a lot more than "DNS issues" if those objects were actually gone.

Without filtering:

[image]

With filtering:

[image]

View menu > Filter - select All Names, then refresh.